# Invalid forward reference, or reference to uncompiled type error

Tags: excel, vba

I've been using VBA for my job for the last five years and I've developed many macros with thousands of lines of code. Many of these macros are used for capturing data during fast paced accounting closes. All of a sudden within the last week multiple users have received the error in the tittle. Most of the macros have worked just fine for months or years. An example of the code receiving the error is below. Does anyone know how I can fix this or what could possibly cause it? The files this is happening in have nothing in common. There are power queries in each file but those power queries are different with different sources. It can't be just my Excel because multiple other users have the problem. I'm thinking it could be some update. I work indirectly for Microsoft so it could be some new update that hasn't been fully released to the public? This is my best guess. Code seems to randomly lose the ability to detect worksheets or workbooks for multiple users.

```
  Sub Sheetfinder()

ty = Application.InputBox("PO Number", "Enter PO number here")
ta = 0

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = ty Then
        sht.Activate
        ta = 1
    End If
Next

If ta = 0 Then
MsgBox "Sheet not found"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the error occur on  specific line?

Answer (score 3):

this happened to me too... by declaring all the worksheets in the form of

dim ws as Worksheet 
set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 
... your code here...

the code will run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

### Invalid Forward Reference...

Here is a [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/exccel-office-365-vba-run-time-error-2147319767/ef41d230-f070-4247-994c-04e1c1d76b29) of someone else encountering the same error. I could not reproduce the error.

**The Issues**

- Your code is working on my end, so it is questionable if the following proposed changes will make a difference on your end.
- It is recommended to use `Option Explicit` which will force you to
  declare all variables.
- If you don't use the `If ty...` line then when the user `cancel`s, the
  code will unnecessarily loop through the worksheets trying to find a worksheet
  named `False`.
- If you don't use `Exit For` then after a worksheet was found, the code will unnecessarily continue looping through the rest of the worksheets.
- IF your code is the complete code, you should consider the `On Error` solution (`SheetFinderOE`).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sheetfinder()

    Dim ty As Variant
    ty = Application.InputBox("PO Number", "Enter PO number here")
    ' Either...
    If ty = False Then MsgBox "Operation cancelled.": Exit Sub
    ' ...or just
    'If ty = False Then Exit Sub

    Dim sht As Worksheet, ta As Long
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name = ty Then
            sht.Activate
            ta = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If ta = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Sheet '" & ty & "' not found"
    End If

End Sub

Sub SheetFinderOE()

    Dim ty As Variant
    ty = Application.InputBox("PO Number", "Enter PO number here")
    If ty = False Then MsgBox "Operation cancelled.": Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ty).Activate
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Sheet '" & ty & "' not found."
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at my Excel.exe file and it had been auto updated at 7:48 AM on Thursday just a couple hours before multiple macros failed in multiple different unconnected documents (some had worked for years). I have a ticket out with MSFT support as the basic problem didn't correct after uninstalling/reinstalling all of Office. However, I am able to get the my code and VBasic2008's code to work by moving all tabs, modules, and power queries to a new workbook.

Once a file has the issue (that still sporadically appears) the following code doesn't work.

```
Sub testing1()

MsgBox Worksheets("PO Tracker").Cells(1, 1)

End Sub

Sub testing2()

MsgBox sheet1.Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Any command using a variable set to a worksheet/workbook, a command to cycle through worksheets, a command to activate worksheets, etc. fails because somehow VBA loses the ability to communicate the command to Excel. However, the code below does work but isn't too useful when the code must use multiple sheets/workbooks.

```
Sub testing1()

MsgBox Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

I have work arounds but ones that general users of the macros don't have the technical skills to implement. If someone has something else I can try please let me know.